# Convert pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, pandas-groupby

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807334/converting-pandas-core-groupby-seriesgroupby-to-dataframe) didn't have a satisfactory answer, so I'm asking it again.

Suppose I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'values': [1, 1, 2, 2]})
```

I group by the first column 'group':

```
g1 = df1.groupby('group')
```

I've now created a "**DataFrame**GroupBy". Then I extract the first column from the GroupBy object:

```
g1_1st_column = g1['group']
```

The type of g1_1st_column is "pandas.core.groupby.**Series**GroupBy". Notice it's not a "**DataFrame**GroupBy" anymore.

My question is, how can I convert the SeriesGroupBy object back to a DataFrame object? I tried using the .to_frame() method, and got the following error:

```
g1_1st_column = g1['group'].to_frame()
```

**AttributeError**: Cannot access callable attribute 'to_frame' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method.

How would I use the apply method, or some other method, to convert to a DataFrame?

Comment: May be: `g1['group'].apply(pd.DataFrame)`

Comment: @ManishSaraswat, that's it! That's the answer. So simple! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Manish Saraswat kindly answered my question in the comments.

```
g1['group'].apply(pd.DataFrame)
```